# Inserir resultado de um script ou o código de um script em uma div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço para ao carregar um *script* em uma pagina,  o resultado apareça em uma `div`?

Exemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/*
   conteúdo do script
*/

</script>

<div id="script" class="000000"></div>
```

O objetivo é que o *script* ao ser carregado na pagina, o seu resultado apareça onde a `div` estiver localizada.

Eu possuo um exemplo aqui:

```
<div id="video" class="UJAwNkhbYWM"></div>

<iframe width="854" height="510" ID="caixa" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<script>
var video = $("#video").attr('class');
$('#caixa').attr('src', "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video);
</script>
```

Com esse código é possível fazer isso com um vídeo do Youtube, porem gostaria de executar o mesmo com um *script*. Tentando esclarecer um pouco mais....

Vejamos o exemplo do Lightbox que é usado para visualizar imagens.
Esse trecho do *script*:

```
$("a[href$='.jpg'], a[href$='.png'], a[href$='.jpeg'], a[href$='.gif']").fancybox();
```

Indica que ao carregar o *script*, e ele encontrando imagens com o final, `.jpg`, `.png` e outros ele vai fazer o efeito desejado.

No caso de um *script* eu queria que ele ao ser executado ele o faça em uma `div` especifica.

Tipo ele encontra a imagem `.png`, mas ele vai mostra ela na Sidebar por exemplo, por que o *script* encontrou a `div` ali.

Comment: Vc quer inserir o resultado de um script ou o código de um script que foi executado?

Comment: O resultado, o script execulta uma função, e o resultado aparece na div

Comment: Isso é muito relativo, se o tal script estiver simplesmente imprimindo direto onde ele estiver, basta coloca-lo dentro da div normalmente, mas se ele estiver modificando o conteúdo de um elemento previamente definido, você pode nomear a div com o mesmo nome, ou identificar o elemento que o script utilizou ou criou e mover o conteúdo para o div usando jquery.

Comment: Cnseguiu pôr isto a funcionar?

Answer (score 3):

A resposta ao seu problema e a resposta à sua pergunta são, a meu ver, ligeiramente diferentes.

**Para carregar um script na página** precisa de uma string com o conteudo do script, depois tem de criar um elemento script que vai ser adicionado à página e aí ele corre diretamente.

Exemplo:

```
var scriptString = "var video = 'uT3SBzmDxGk';$('#caixa').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + video);";
var script = document.createElement('script');
script = $(script).append(scriptString);
$('#novoScript').html(script); // podia tambem ser "$(document.body).append(script);"
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p0pahbep/2

**Para mudar o video dentro da iFrame** não precisa de ter um novo script a ser adicionado à página. Aqui o melhor é ter um oscultador de eventos que escuta um `click` em elementos com uma dada classe. Aí vai ter de alterar o HTML um pouco.

Por exemplo:

HTML

```
<div class="video" data-youtubeid="UJAwNkhbYWM">Video 1</div>
<div class="video" data-youtubeid="gIdqiis3Mts">Video 1</div>
<div class="video" data-youtubeid="Q78COTwT7nE">Video 1</div>
<div class="video" data-youtubeid="Z88qapIgOLg">Video 1</div>
<div class="video" data-youtubeid="oUX2RSyLw3w">Video 1</div>
<iframe width="854" height="510" ID="caixa" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

JavaScript / jQuery

```
$('.video').on('click', function () {
    var video = $(this).data('youtubeid');
    $('#caixa').attr('src', "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video);
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/togzdkgu/