# Executar script em uma <div>

Tags: javascript, html

Eu possuo esse script. O que eu devo acrescentar nele para que, ao ser executado, apareça em uma `<div>`?

Aqui está o script:

```
// Which flash versions are needed for given format
var FLASH_VERSIONS = {
    '7/0/0': [5],
    '9/0/115': [18, 22, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 59, 78, 82, 83, 84, 85, 120, 121],
    '10/1/0': [52, 53, 54, 60],
    };

// Regex to extract the video format
var RE_ITAG = /&itag=([0-9]*)&/i;

function get_fmt(content) {
    var fmt = new Object();
    fmt.list = new Array();
    fmt.stream_map = new Array();

    for (var i=0; i < content.length; i++) {
        var url = content[i]['url'];
        if (url.search("") == -1)
            continue;

        var matches = RE_ITAG.exec(url);
        var itag = matches[1];

        var resolution = '7/0/0';
        for (var possible_resolution in FLASH_VERSIONS.length) {
            if (FLASH_VERSIONS[possible_resolution].indexOf(itag)) {
                resolution = possible_resolution;
            }
        }

        fmt.list.push(itag+'/'+String(content[i].width)+'x'+String(content[i].height)+'/'+resolution);
        fmt.stream_map.push(itag+'|'+content[i].url.replace(/,/g, '%2C'));
    }

    fmt.list.reverse();
    fmt.stream_map.reverse();
    return fmt;
}

function get_embed(content) {
    var fmt = get_fmt(content);
    var flashvars = new Array();
    flashvars.push('fs=1');
    flashvars.push('hl=en');
    flashvars.push('autoplay=1');
    flashvars.push('ps=');
    flashvars.push('playerapiid=uniquePlayerId');
    flashvars.push('fmt_list='+encodeURIComponent(fmt.list.join()));
    flashvars.push('fmt_stream_map='+encodeURIComponent(fmt.stream_map.join()));
    flashvars.push('');
    flashvars.push('t=1');
    flashvars.push('vq=large');
    flashvars.push('auth_timeout=86400000000');

    var embed = document.createElement('');
    embed.setAttribute("src", "");
    embed.setAttribute("type", "application/x-shockwave-flash");
    embed.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "true");
    embed.setAttribute("allowscriptaccess", "always");
    embed.setAttribute("scale", "noScale");
    embed.setAttribute("wmode", "opaque");
    embed.setAttribute("flashvars", flashvars.join("&"));
    embed.setAttribute("width", "100%");
    embed.setAttribute("height", "100%");
    return embed;
}

var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
var script = document.createElement('script');
var hash = document.location.hash;
var id = hash.substr(1,hash.length);
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
var script = document.createElement('script');

script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
script.setAttribute('src', 'https://');
head.appendChild(script);

myFunction(); // Fails because it hasn't loaded from my.js yet.    
    window.onload = function() {
        // Works most of the time but not all of the time.
        // Especially if my.js injects another script that contains myFunction().
        myFunction();
    };
```

Como faço para ele ao ser carregado numa pagina html apareça dentro da div especifica?

Exemplo:

```
<div id="script" class="#">/div>
```

Comment: Uma duvida... o que tem na váriavel ts?

Comment: Se refere a essa parte Math.round(ts/3600  ?  ali ira aparece uma embed

Comment: Retirei aquela parte. ela não era para esta ali

Comment: Como já te disseram [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29334/inserir-resultado-de-um-script-ou-o-c%C3%B3digo-de-um-script-em-uma-div) (aliás, é a mesma pergunta, não?), não existe isso de "o script aparecer dentro de uma div". Depende do que o script faz. Ele pode escrever conteúdo em algum lugar ou não. Qual é o script que você está tentando executar? Pegando esse seu exemplo, qual seria o conteúdo de `myFunction`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remova esta parte do script, ela é desnecessária:

```
myFunction(); // Fails because it hasn't loaded from my.js yet.

window.onload = function() {
    // Works most of the time but not all of the time.
    // Especially if my.js injects another script that contains myFunction().
    myFunction();
};
```

Agora repare nesta linha:

```
script.setAttribute('src', 'https://?authuser=0&alt=jsonm&urlredir=1&commentreason=1&fd=shapes&thumbsize=d&max-results=100&callback=picasa_callback&t=');
```

Em particular, nisto aqui:

```
callback=picasa_callback
```

Quando o script for inserido, a função indicada como *callback* será chamada. Neste caso, é a função `picasa_callback`. Agora veja como ela é:

```
function picasa_callback(obj) {
    document.body.appendChild(get_embed(obj['feed']['media']['content']));
}
```

Ela pega um HTML (gerado por `get_embed`) e insere no final do `<body>`, com `document.body.appendChild`. Se você quer inserir esse HTML na sua div com id `script`, faça o append nela e não no body:

```
function picasa_callback(obj) {
    document.getElementById('script').appendChild(get_embed(obj['feed']['media']['content']));
}
```

**Importante:** para garantir que a div exista quando o callback for chamado, inclua seu script no final do HTML. Certifique-se que o script esteja depois do `<div id="script" class="#"></div>` no código-fonte.

Comment: Mas nesse caso o user vai fica exposto no html?

Comment: Sim, você não tem como evitar isso. No HTML (opção "exibir código fonte") ele não vai aparecer porque foi injetado, mas qualquer inspetor de código será capaz de ver essa url.

Comment: Seria possivel troca a id do user apenas pela div?  tipo '+id+'

Comment: Não entendi ...

Comment: Digo ao inves de usa o script em varios lugares, usaria o mesmo script, apenas alterando pela div o user ou o video carregado

Comment: Acho que sim, vai brincando com o script e experimentando.

Comment: Tentei fazer ele carrega pela div usando a class mas não deu, tem alguma ideia de como fazer? <div id="script" class="100642868990821651444/albumid/5720909216955340593/photoid/5720909218315234178"></div>

Answer (score 1):

Eu sugiro usar a biblioteca JQuery pro mater compatibilidade com diversos navegadorse e pode usar o código:

link para incluir a lib:

```
<script src ="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Código Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $('#script').append('<div></div>');
});
```

Pode dar uma olhada no JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/L1ufwdt9/4/

Comment: Da para fazer apenas com java?

Comment: Você quer dizer Javascript? Não tem porque, dá sim, vou modificar lá no JS Fiddle.

Comment: Assim, na verdade dá, mas não é cross-browser e se você utilizar mais de uma imagem, ou iFrame na página, ele vai carregar diversas vezes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-onclick-fu

Comment: O codigo não funciona, aparece apenas a letra que você adicionou ali

Comment: Acho que não entendi sua pergunta então, o que você quer adicionar dentro da div? eu adicionei uma outra div com o conteúdo 'b'

Comment: O objetivo é fazer o script carrega na div, o script carrega e aparece na div

Comment: O script que te passei carrega uma div dentro de outra div, o que tu quer que apareça dentro dela?